# 3D scene output to pdf in processing: depth buffer issue

Tags: pdf-generation, processing, depth-buffer

In a processing sketch, I export a 3D scene into a PDF file, using `beginRaw()` and `endRaw()`.

The depth order in the output is wrong. Triangles are rendered in the same order I define them in my `beginShape()`/`endShape()` structure, rather than according to their z-buffer position.

This happens indifferently whether i use `P3D` or `OPENGL` as the rendering scheme.
Also whether I do or don't activate `GL_ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST` / `GL_ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT` with the `hint()` function.

[image: processing window]

[image: pdf output]

I looked around, googled a lot, and was surprised to find that no one brought this up.
Can anyone confirm that this is a bug in processing?

Or am I missing something crucial here?

Here's a minimal code reproducing the problematic behavior.

```
import processing.pdf.*;

color faceXColor, faceYColor, faceZColor;

float rotx = PI/4;
float roty = PI/3;

void setup()
{   
  size(500, 360, P3D);

  faceXColor = color( 255, 0, 0 );
  faceYColor = color( 0, 255, 0 );
  faceZColor = color( 0, 0, 255 );
}

void draw()
{ 
  background( color(155) );

  pushMatrix();

  translate(width/2.0, height/2.0, -100);

  rotateX(rotx);
  rotateY(roty);

  scale(90);

  noStroke();

  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);

  beginShape(TRIANGLES);


  fill( faceZColor );   // BLUE
    // +Z "front" face
  vertex(-1, -1,  1 );
  vertex( 1, -1,  1 );
  vertex( 1,  1,  1 );

  // -Z "back" face
  vertex( 1, -1, -1 );
  vertex(-1, -1, -1 );
  vertex(-1,  1, -1 );

  fill( faceYColor );  // GREEN
  // +Y "bottom" face
  vertex(-1,  1,  1 );
  vertex( 1,  1,  1 );
  vertex( 1,  1, -1 );

  // -Y "top" face
  vertex(-1, -1, -1 );
  vertex( 1, -1, -1 );
  vertex( 1, -1,  1 );

  fill( faceXColor );  // RED
  // +X "right" face
  vertex( 1, -1,  1 );
  vertex( 1, -1, -1 );
  vertex( 1,  1, -1 );

  // -X "left" face
  vertex(-1, -1, -1 );
  vertex(-1, -1,  1 );
  vertex(-1,  1,  1 );

  endShape();

  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed( )
{
  beginRaw(PDF, "output.pdf"); 
  draw();
  endRaw();
}

void mouseDragged() {
  float rate = 0.01;
  rotx += (pmouseY-mouseY) * rate;
  roty += (mouseX-pmouseX) * rate;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire code, so others can attempt to replicate the bug?

Comment: It _is_ the entire code, you just have to scroll down to the end in the code window. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Okay. "Here's a minimal code snippet" made me think that it wasn't the full code.

Comment: Sure. I edited the text accordingly.

Comment: I just attempted to replicate this. Unfortunately, my graphics card is super-outdated, so I get some stupid `FramBufferObjectsNotSuppoted` (or something like that) error. I wish you luck in figuring out what's wrong!

Comment: I just got it working, and am having the same problem.

Comment: My guess is the problem is with the [PGraphicsPDF](https://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/pdf/src/processing/pdf/PGraphicsPDF.java?r=5606) renderer since it extends PGraphicsJava2D. How about rendering a large (300dpi) tiff instead ? It's not vector, but it look ok when printed

Comment: A reply on the Processing forum by codeanticode hints at a bug, that could be fixed by implementing depth sorting — somewhere in the `PGraphicsOpenGL` class routines. See http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/1509/3d-scene-output-to-pdf-depth-buffer-issue#Item_2. I'm looking into the sources.